# How to avoid horizontal scrollbar in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, highcharts

I am redering a highchart in a container. I want this chart to fit in container and to not to show any scroll. But it gives me a horizontal scroll with no/ or very little space to scroll.

```
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"     align="right"></div>
```

Somthing similar to  - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2K8uW/1/)
And also when I try to debug using f12 , scroll disappears.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Try this css rule:  `overflow-x:hidden;` Add this rule wehre the element is making the scroolbar.

Comment: Luis, this scrollbar is one from highchart itself - its not a browser scrollbar. In case of a browser scroll bar this should solve it indeed.

Answer (score 5):

add

```
scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
},
```

to your `xAxis` attribute of chart when initializing in javascript.

Comment: -I tried doing this. But It didnt work. I have solved issue for now by setting ovarflow propery of outer container to hidden

Answer (score 2):

You must change it

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: false
},
```